# How do I change Swift Mailer configuration to spool emails when there is no config file when installed from composer

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer

I have installed Swift Mailer using Composer, and it's all set up and working well. But now I want it to use a spool rather than sending emails immediately. The little documentation I can find says I need to specify certain settings in config/packages/swiftmailer.php but I don't have that file.

```
// config/packages/swiftmailer.php
$container->loadFromExtension('swiftmailer', [
    // ...
    'spool' => ['type' => 'memory'],
]);
```

How can I setup Swift Mailer to use spool rather than sending email immediately?

Answer (score 0):

Following https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html#configuration it's in `config/packages/swiftmailer.yaml` and not `.php`.

If you are using and older (and unmaintained) version of Symfony ?
In this case it would be in `app/config/config.yml`
(https://symfony.com/doc/2.8/email.html#configuration)

Comment: I just installed swiftmailer into my project using composer. Not using Symfony as a whole, just this and a couple of other packages.